# What to do if I sold my MacBook Air and didn't disable iCloud

Tags: icloud, macbook-pro, security

I recently sold my MacBook Air, and I deauthorized iTunes, wiped the hard drive, and reinstalled snow leopard (the os version that came installed with the MBA).

I stumbled upon this shortly after, which made me very nervous since I didn't do it.

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5189

This is what I didn't do:

> Turn off Find My Mac and sign out of iCloud
>
> To turn off the iCloud service on your Mac:
>
> Choose System Preferences > iCloud. Deselect Find My Mac to disconnect
>   your devices from iCloud. Click the Sign Out button on the left side.
>   The system automatically removes iCloud data from all of your devices.

How nervous about this should I be? Also, is there anything I can do now that the computer is not in my possession?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not at all - when you wiped the drive, the iCloud registration token for that device was wiped as well.

The only remnants of your account on that Mac might be your FindMyMac token that gets stored on the Recovery HD.

You might contact the seller and lest them choose whether you will send a remote wipe at their convenience to clear that. If they enable Find My Mac - they will see your email and be able to remove your hold on tracking at device.

If you can't or don't want to contact the buyer, you could also just forget that device using the web interface to iCloud or the Find My Phone app on iOS.

Again, the person can't get at your information or log in as you - just that computer might still check in depending on how exactly you wiped the storage drive.

Comment: Yup - other than you snooping on the Mac, there's nothing serious you are exposed to after a wipe.

Answer (score 4):

This is not entirely true. If you do not remove your iCloud account from your old device, it will remain with that device. Our company sold our fleet of Mac Air's and a few had iCloud set up. These machines were all wiped and re-imaged, then sold. The new users never set up iCloud so that account is blank. HOWEVER, we still had access to those sold machines via iCloud! We could wipe and/or lock at-will, even after removing that device from your iCloud account. Annoying and potentially dangerous. You have to have the new user create a new iCloud account and request approval from the old user to proceed. Ridiculous! We ran around in circles with this problem when a few of our employees noticed they could track their old Mac's after sold. Oops. Now we know disassociating before sale is imperative.

Answer (score 0):

Go to iCloud.com and a list of devices associated with you account will appear. If iCloud is still active on your previous device, you can locate, erase, or disassociate your account with the selected device after signing in. Easy peasy. I found this out when mom's adult links popped up in my current computer's faves and who wants to know about that. I'm wiser now.