# Selling water damaged MacBook Air 2017: Is it safe to simply remove the SSD?

Tags: macbook-pro, security, hardware, ssd

I water damaged my Macbook Air 2017 and it will no longer turn on. I was thinking of selling the MBA for some money but wanted to make sure that my security is not compromised.

If I remove the SSD from the motherboard (and sell it without the SSD), am I safe to assume that none of my personal data is still on the laptop?

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: With regard to your post, you're actually asking two separate questions here (i.e. one about the SSD, the other about iCloud). While I see how these are related in your scenario, they're actually distinct questions and, being a Q&A site, things work best when your question is specific to one issue. Because of this I've edited that out, but you may want to refer to [What to do if I sold my MacBook Air and didn't disable iCloud](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/76554/what-to-do-if-i-sold-my-macbook-air-and-didnt-disable-icloud) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can assume that none of your data is still on the MacBook Air. All personal data stored on the laptop itself is stored on the SSD, so removing this effectively removes the data from the laptop.

It is also possible that the SSD is still fully functioning, so if you made the mistake of not backing up your data, you may be able to still access it from the SSD, via adaptors, external enclosures or another MBA of the same generation.

You may also want to refer to Apple's advice on [what to do before you sell, give away, or trade in your Mac](https://support.apple.com/HT201065).